# By reversing the orientation of at most k arcs. can $D$ be made not strongly connected?

Tags: graph-theory

Let $D$ be a digraph and suppose that $D$ can be made not strongly
connected by deleting $k$ arcs, for some integer $k$.
Prove that $D$ can be made not strongly connected by
reversing the orientation of at most $k$ arcs.

Do really the assumption enable us to solve this question? Any hint is appreciated.